# "C'est La VR" – Does this make sense in French?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, questions, france

I'm wondering about 'C'est la VR' for a brand name. Many know the phrase 'C'est la vie'. Is 'VR' understood and used commonly in French for 'virtual reality' and could 'c'est la VR' work in French as a creative play on words?

Thanks,

Asa.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it doesn't work, it just sounds odd.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to write a slogan in French?

Comment: @Lambie Yeah, a creative brand name or website title idea for VR. Clearly it works more as a play on words for those who speak english since we pronounce VR as "Vie-ar" & use "C'est la vie".

Answer (score 5):

Virtual reality in French is [réalité virtuelle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9alit%C3%A9_virtuelle). If I had seen *C'est la VR* I absolutely never would have guessed what it meant, but I'm not "in" that sort of thing.  Although some people [use VR](https://www.futura-sciences.com/tech/definitions/technologie-realite-virtuelle-598/) in French, if you want to use initials you'd better take the French initials RV [which are more often used](http://www.immersion.fr/realite-virtuelle-realite-mixte-realite-augmentee/) in French. It depends if you want to be understood by a more general public or not.

I doubt a French person would see any "creative play on words" in "c'est la VR"  because the letter V is not pronounced like the word *vie* in French: *C'est la vie*  [sɛlavi] / *C'est la VR* [sɛlavɛɛʁ].

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, but I think now "VR" is used much more than "RV". Brand themselves use the term "Casque VR" exclusively, I don't think I've ever seen "Casque RV" anywhere in the last 5 years. But as you said it's pronounced as French letters (\ve.ɛʁ\\) so it doesn't work as a pun on "*C'est la vie*".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat that's why I mentioned the general public, by that I meant people like me who don't usually go for that sort of thing, that excludes brand material among other things. I expect I'm not the only one to only speak of *réalité virtuelle* in full and never use the initials. Generation gap most probably!

Comment: Other than abbreviating réalité virtuelle in articles and academic stuff, I would also expect VR to be preferred most of the time, especially for a broader audience. Someone who isn't interested in VR probably have no idea what RV is, but there is a chance that he saw or heard VR somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for every comment here! Very very helpful to understand this in full. :)

Comment: Can I ask, as a final question: Does 'C'est la VR' work as a statement (if not a pun)? Does it mean 'This is VR'?

Comment: @Asa *C'est la VR* works as a statement and if in context there's no problem to understand what VR refers to, but out of the blue I'm not sure people who are not familiar with the initials understand, it depends who you are talking to.

Comment: @None Thank you so much  :)